# What Analytics service works with iOS 10 for iMessage apps/extension?

Tags: ios10, twitter-fabric, imessage

I need to integrate Analytics for my iMessage app.
Installed Fabric SDK in the app but it seems that events are not really being sent to the service.
Any workaround? any other service I could use?

Comment: Did you find a good alternative for event analytics for iMessage extensions?

Answer (score 1):

You can track and attribute installs with Branch: [Setting Up Your iOS 10 iMessages App With Attribution and Deep Linking](https://blog.branch.io/setting-up-your-ios-10-imessages-app-with-attribution-and-deep-linking?utm_campaign=Q316-PremiumSolutions&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=34267339&_hsenc=p2ANqtz--GRCDBT8zNtElVkHWKqnFCz4BGHMPRkkzPbg1WJS2HGjPalQOfXPYfmjMBfHH7BMaGxj9b7j_2Q_6frJf6FNyoP7VAiw&_hsmi=34271095)

Comment: Mixpanel supports app extensions aswell

Comment: @warpling I prefer an analytics tool and not deep linking oriented tool. Just installs are not interesting.

Comment: @LA You are right, Mixpanel support but it is too costly for the value

Comment: @ldan you should update your question if you have requirements.

Comment: Do either of these support iMessage extension-only? We don't ship a home screen app, just an extension.